# How do I switch between GPUS on Ubuntu?

Tags: intel-graphics, amd-graphics, gpu, amdgpu, switchable-graphics

One of my laptops (Acer Aspire Timeline 5820TZG) has two GPUs. First the integrated Intel one, and second an AMD Radeon HD. When I'm running Windows, I can use the Amethyst Control Center to switch between cards.

On Ubuntu, I actually don't even know what card is processing my graphics, let alone how to change it. For some programs like OBS, which don't work on Ubuntu at the moment, I'm hoping they might work with the other GPU, so I'd like to be able to switch between them. What should I do?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1286585/1210606

Comment: @24601 The question is about hybrid graphics, not multiple monitors ;)

Comment: @24601 Not really. Settings > Screens shows the monitor(s). Settings > About shows the basic hardware specifications and yes, graphics is there and that should be the graphics card/chip in use. "Settings > Screen Display" is certainly not found in standard Ubuntu, maybe in one of the flavors?

Comment: `For some programs like OBS, which don't work on Ubuntu at the moment` -- OBS works for me even without a dedicated graphics card. What issue did you encounter?

Answer (score 0):

You can check which GPU is used by running

```
glxinfo | grep OpenGL
```

With AMD dual graphics you can switch GPU by setting `DRI_PRIME` variable.